# how to do image fusion using dwt in matlab for 40 input images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have done image fusion for 2 input images code as follows,how to code this program when i use 40 input images and get 1 fused image as output.

close all;

```
clear all;
a =imread('D:\\project code\\samples\\peyrou_over.jpg');
b= imread('D:\\project code\\samples\\peyrou_under.jpg');

[k1,k2]=size(a);

%1-dwt(haar wavelet transform)
[a1,h1,v1,d1]=dwt2(a,'haar');
%figure;imshow([a1,h1;v1,d1],[]);
%hold on;
[a2,h2,v2,d2]=dwt2(b,'haar');
%figure;imshow([a2,h2;v2,d2], []);



%max fusion rule
for i=1:k1
    for j=1:k2
        a3(i,j)=max(a1(i,j),a2(i,j));
        h3(i,j)=max(h1(i,j),h2(i,j));
        v3(i,j)=max(v1(i,j),v2(i,j));
        d3(i,j)=max(d1(i,j),d2(i,j));
    end
end

%reconstruction of fused image
c=idwt2(a3,h3,v3,d3,'haar');

figure,imshow(a)
title('First Image')
figure,imshow(b)
title('Second Image')
figure,imshow(c)
title('Fused Image')
```

Comment: Why not just take the fusion result of first 2 images and fuse it with the third image and so on?

Comment: Thank you for  helping.I understood what  u are saying if u help to explain with a line of code it would be more helpful.